# Java native browser login prompt

Tags: java, android, https

I am trying to make a HTTPS call using Java to a browser that uses the native login prompt.

http://blog.stevensanderson.com/2008/08/25/using-the-browsers-native-login-prompt/

Currently I'm using the below for HTTP and it works fine for other websites since I know the parameters to put in...however it fails for the above type of login (I am not sure how to capture the parameters...it's a login pop up..or if this is even the correct approach)....any ideas??..thanks

```
HttpUtility.sendPostRequest(requestURL, params);
String[] response = HttpUtility.readMultipleLinesRespone();
```

Answer (score 0):

The server should respond to your first request with a `WWW-Authenticate` header and a status of 401. The header will contain details of the kind of authentication it's expecting.

Then you can try again after adding an `Authorization` header to your request in the correct format.

Answer (score 0):

@alex: OK...I managed to make the HTTPS connection following your suggestion with this:

```
URL url = new URL("https://www.example.com/Login");
URLConnection urlConnection = url.openConnection();
urlConnection.setRequestProperty("Authorization", "Basic " + authString);
InputStream is = urlConnection.getInputStream();
InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(is);

//then I read the input stream..
```

But when I tried to make another connection (say go to a different page after login) with this code in another method...taking URLConnection as the parameter:

```
//Below is in a method called account(URLConnection urlConnection)

URL url = new URL("https://www.example.com/account.aspx");
urlConnection = url.openConnection();
InputStream is = urlConnection.getInputStream();
InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(is);

//again I read the input stream..
```

...it throws the below exception...same exception before logging in..how can I rectify?

```
Server returned HTTP response code: 401 for URL: https://www.example.com/account.aspx
```

Answer (score 0):

You have probably moved on from this problem, but I recently had an issue that involved achieving functionality similar to the browser's native login prompt. I have solved it and written a post about it. Steven Sanderson's post was helpful for me too, in helping me understand certain concepts.

http://captaindanko.blogspot.com.au/2015/04/how-does-browsers-native-login-prompt.html